# How to delete temporary files of deleted objects in R package raster

Tags: r, object, temporary-files

Since I work with large RasterBrick objects, the objects can't be stored in memory but are stored as temporary files in the current Temporary files directory tempdir() or to be exact in the subfolder "raster". 
Due to the large file sizes it would be very nice to delete the temporary files of the unused objects.

If I delete objects I no longer need by

rm(list=ls(pattern="xxx")

the temporary files still exist.
Garbage collection gc() will have no effect on that to my understanding since it has no effect on the hard drive.
The automatically given names of the temporary files don't show any relation to the object names.
Therefore it is not possible to delete them by a code like

raster_temp_dir <- paste(tempdir(), "/raster", sep="")
files_to_be_removed <- list.files(rastertemp, pattern="xxx", full.names=T)

Unfortunately the files of objects still in use aren't read-only.
Therefore I also would delete objects I still need by running:

files_to_be_removed <- list.files(rastertemp, full.names=T)

Did somebody already solve this problem or has any ideas how to solve it?
It would be perfect if somehow, there a code could distinguish between unused and used objects.
Since this is unlikely to implement a detour could be naming the temporary files of the Raster objects manually, but I haven't encountered an option for this neither since the filename argument can only be used when writing files to the hard disk but not when temporary files are created (to my knowledge).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you're looking for is `file.remove()`. Just pass it a vector with the file names you want to delete.